# IE7 bug with div that changes the height

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

I have a code like this:

```
<body>
    <div id='wrapper'>
        <div id='content'>
          <!--content that changes his height-->
        </div>
        <div id='footer'>
          <!--Footer content-->
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And the css is something like this:

```
#wrapper{
   width : 1024px;
   position : relative;
}
#footer{
  position : absolute;
  bottom : 0;
  left : 0;
}
```

Inside the div#content I have some divs that can be expanded or reduced, so when they are expanded its height increase, increasing the height of the container div#wrapper. In all modern browsers, the footer position is recalculated properly and the footer is placed at the very bottom of the wrapper div, but in IE7 that doesn't occur: the footer remain in the same place that was before the wrapper increase its height.

Making some googling, I found that the most likely reason for this behavior was the "hasLayout bug", so I added the property *zoom : 1* to the div#wrapper, but the problem didn't disappear, so I tried adding this property to other elements like the #footer without any success.

I am completely clueless...

Anyone has some idea of what is going on?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You've got two elements with the ID of 'wrapper'. Should one of these be 'footer'?

Comment: your problem is because you have `position:absolute` for your footer.

Comment: Yes Billy, the second one should be 'footer'.

Comment: Andrew, Why the position:absolute is a problem? Originally, it haven't  the position:absolute, but then, when I expanded the wrapper, the footer placed Ok, but when I reduced it again, the footer totally screw up, placing in the wrong place and changing the height and width.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally I found a solution. I removed the position : absolute, and I set the height and width of the footer. Here I found something weirder ( at least for me it was). The wrapper has a width of 1024 px. If I set the width of the footer to 1024 px, it overflow the wrapper using more than 1024 px. If I set the width to 100%, the same problem. I had to set the width to 91,5% to adjust it to the 1024 px of the wrapper. Somebody knows the reason for this?

Thanks for the comments.

Comment: Maybe because IE 7 sets some weird paddings/margins/borders somewhere in its chaos of overflowed divs. To be safe, just use a reset css (http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)